# Groups of Order $pq$ and Cayley's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It's been a while since my last course on abstract algebra and I'm going through all of the exercises in Herstein's *Topics in Algebra* to refresh myself. This one comes from the section on Cayley's theorem. It's one of the harder starred problems:

"Let $o(G)$ be $pq$, $p>q$ are primes, prove $G$ has a subgroup of order $p$ and a subgroup of order $q$."

Now I know this can easily be proved with Sylow's theorem or Cauchy's theorem, but those topics aren't introduced until later on in this book.

If $G$ has an element $g$ of order $pq$, then $G$ must be cyclic, in which case $\langle g^q\rangle$ and $\langle g^p\rangle$ are subgroups of order $p$ and $q$, respectively.

We can then consider the case where $G$ is not cyclic. Since the order of $G$ is clearly not prime, $G$ must have a nontrivial subgroup, $H$. By Lagrange its order must be of order $p$ or $q$. I think the idea is to prove that the existence of one such subgroup implies the existence of the other.

If the order of $H$ is $p$, then its index in $G$ is $q$. One of the corollaries to Cayley's theorem says that since $o(G) \nmid [G:H]!$, $H$ must contain a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$. This condition is met since $pq \nmid q!$ because $p>q$. Since $H$ itself has prime order, the only nontrivial subgroup of $G$ it contains is itself, so $H$ must be normal in $G$.

That's what I have so far. I would then try to use this to show the existence of a subgroup of order $q$. Then I would try to do the reverse and show that the existence of a subgroup of order $q$ implies the existence of another subgroup of order $p$. Is there a better way (that uses Cayley's theorem and not Sylow/Cauchy)?

Thank you!

Comment: The proof of Cauchy's Theorem is very elementary. It is really natural to use it here. I also have seen questions about group so f order $pq$, where Lagrange's Theorem "is not allowed" to be used, or properties of a product of primes $pq$ are not allowed to be used. I think this is not reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that all elements different from $e$ have order $p$.

Then, the union of all subgroups of order $p$ is the whole group.
Moreover, any two such subgroups are either equal or have trivial intersection.
Therefore, if $n$ is the number of subgroups of order $p$, then
$n(p-1)+1=pq$ and so
$$
n=\frac{pq-1}{p-1}=q +\frac{q-1}{p-1}
$$
But this is never an integer if $p>q \ge 2$. Therefore, there is at least one element of order $q$.

We still need to prove that there is at least one element of order $p$.
Unfortunately, the argument cannot be repeated swapping $p$ and $q$.